# How can I use xlsxwriter and Excelwriter together to populate an excel file which contains some formatted text as well as python exported DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, export-to-excel, xlsxwriter

I am writing a program in python that will work on a csv dataset. The aim of the code is to export the aggregated output in an excel, along with hardcoded header information. The excel file is a final report that is sent to the client; means full and final (as shown in below image). [image]

This is how I begin:
I first created a typical header of the report using xlsxwriter and then tried to export the summary DataFrame (i.e. main table output) below the header using Excelwriter- DataFrame.to_excel

But as soon as I paste the DataFrame in the excel template I created in above step, the initially created header is wiped out, the cells appear blank. And only the DataFrame (table output) is displayed.

[image]

Alternatively, if I first export the dataFrame to the excel and then try to add a header to the excel report, header remains but the DataFrame is gone now. 
[image]

What should I do in order to retain both; dataframe (table output) and header information? I used xlsxwritter, excelwriter of pandas.

Below are few lines of codes that might be important to explain the story.

```py
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('SampleReport_1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

    workbook = writer.book
    WS_I = workbook.add_worksheet('I')

    with ExcelWriter('SampleReport_1.xlsx') as writer:
        dfI.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='I', header=True, index=True, startrow=9, startcol=0, engine=xlsxwriter, merge_cells=True)
    writer.save()

    cell_format1 = workbook.add_format()
    cell_format1.set_bold()

    for worksheet in workbook.worksheets():
        worksheet.write('A1', 'Exhibit', cell_format1)
    workbook.close()
```

Comment: "If I first populate the excel and then try to format the excel report, format remains but values are gone" - what do you mean by "values are gone"?

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for reading my post. Well, I have edited this post as the problem was not explained clearly in the previous post. Could you please refer to the updated post? Would be happy to clarify further if you do not understand the problem even after referring to the updated post.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand: what does "the DataFrame is gone" mean? Maybe if you post 3-4 rows of your dataframe right before you write it to anything, things will be clearer.

Comment: Sorry @JackFleeting. I have made edits in my original post. I have replaced the word "Formatting" by the word "Header".  Hope now it becomes clear. I have added images as well in order to explain the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think I now get what the problem is. I tried the following approach on a sample Excel sheet with a preexiting header and it worked:

First - save your dataframe to csv

```
SampleReport_1_csv = df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\[your path]\SampleReport_1.csv', index = None, header=True)
```

Then open the Excel sheet with the preformatted header and (depending on your version of Excel) import the csv file by going to "data/get external data/from text". Importantly, in the last import step, Excel will ask you for the cell into which the csv is to be imported - make sure that that cell is under the preformatted block (I think it's cell A10, in your case).

Let me know if that works.

Comment: this works. But in this case I have to manually select the tables from another sheet. So it is not serving the purpose of fully automating the Excel report. Am I right?

Comment: @Bunny - What do you exactly mean by "manually select the tables from another sheet"?

Comment: It means, I can not do it using my code. I have to first create a header excel file, then a pandas dataframe output csv file and then go to my excel file and import this dataframe file. Too many different tasks. My motive to create this Excel report using pandas is to minimize number of tasks and basically to create a report on single click (with single 'Restart and Run all cells' in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I found the below solution:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('SampleReport_1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

workbook = writer.book
WS_I = workbook.add_worksheet('I')
cell_format1 = workbook.add_format()
cell_format1.set_bold()

for worksheet in workbook.worksheets():
    worksheet.write('A1', 'Exhibit', cell_format1)
workbook.close()
WS_I.add_table('A3:G6', {'data': dfI_new.values.tolist(),'header_row': True})
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a 2nd excel file with formatted template and link each cell to the 1st excel file. As long as you enable the link, changes to your python output should populate in the "template" excel file.